# Вопрос про продвижение типов

Tags: java, преобразование-типов

Читаю Java 8, Полное руководство. Там Шилдт пишет про очень интересную вещь - автоматическое продвижение типов. Вот один из примеров:

```
byte b = 5;
b = b * 2;

System.out.println(b); // ошибка!
```

Тк при умножении тип операндов автоматически продвигается к типу int. Поэтому приходится использовать явное приведение типов.
А теперь вопрос - почему когда мы пишем так:

```
byte b = 5;
b *= 2;
System.out.println(b);

//Все ОК!
```

Почему не происходит ошибки?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В примере Вы не совсем правильно отметили где именно происходит ошибка, `System.out.println` здесь не причем.

Соответственно, возникают два вопроса: (1) почему операторы арифметических операторов (+, -, *, /) требуют приведения типа, и (2) почему составные операторы присваивания (+=, -=, *=, /=) приведения не требуют.

```
byte b = 100;
b *= 2;   //все нормально
b = 2*b;  //error: incompatible types: possible lossy conversion from int to byte
```

Формальные ответы можно найти в спецификации Java.

### Арифметические операторы

В пункте [5.6. «Numeric Contexts»](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6) описывается, что все числовые типы, кроме double, float и long в арифметическом контексте приводятся к int:

> In a numeric arithmetic context or a numeric array context, the promoted type is int, and any expressions that are not of type int undergo widening primitive conversion to int.

Сделано это чтобы подчеркнуть что на низком уровне все целочисленные операции проводятся на 32-битных значения. Также в этом случае не нужно писать правила приведения для каждой пары типов (byte, char, short).

### Составные операторы присваивания

В пункте [15.26.2 «Составные операторы присваивания»](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) написано, что эти операторы эквивалентны арифметической операции с приведением типа:

> A compound assignment expression of the form E1 op= E2 is equivalent to E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), where T is the type of E1, except that E1 is evaluated only once.
> For example, the following code is correct:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;  
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> and results in x having the value 7 because it is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;  
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```
>
> ***Перевод***
> Выражение составного присваивания вида E1 op= E2 эквивалентно E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2)), где T представляет собой тип E1, с тем отличием, что E1 вычисляется только однократно.
> Например, следующий код корректен:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;  
> x += 4.6;
> ```
>
> и результат, сохраненный в x имеет значение 7, поскольку этот код эквивалентен следующему:
>
> ```
> short x = 3;  
> x = (short)(x + 4.6);
> ```

Тут нужно заметить, что если бы эти операторы не выполняли бы приведения типов, то их нельзя было бы применить для byte и short вообще:

```
byte a = 1;
byte b = 2;
a += b;  //это работает только потому что выполняется приведение
a = a + b; //а это не работает, т.к. выражение имеет тип int
```

Answer (score 3):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

*= и подобные операторы (+= , -= и тд) неявно преобразуют к тому типу, который слева.
сдесь `b = b * 2;`
компилятор автоматически приводит к типу int чтобы не было потери точности(неявное преведение) `b` превратилось в `int` , `b * 2` тоже `int` и мы не можем присвоить `int` в `byte` без явного приведения `b = (byte) ( b * 2);`

очень советую посмотреть лекции тагира валеева на ютубе,
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLlb7e2G7aSpRZSRZxANkvpYC82BXUzCTY